# åäö filenames not working after moving website to new host

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, apache-httpd, filenames

I recently moved a Wordpress site from `one.com` to a linux vps server running Ubuntu 16 with Apache. Everything works fine except images with åäö which show as broken, right clicking and copying the link shows the following.

```
/images/vara-p%C3%A5l%C3%A4st1.jpg
```

As soon as you paste this in the browser address bar and hit enter it gets turned into

```
/images/vara-påläst1.jpg
```

And shows a 404 error. I navigated to `/images/` which lists all the files in the directory and I can see that `vara-påläst1.jpg` is there.

copying the link from the images folder gives me the following

```
/images/vara-pa%cc%8ala%cc%88st1.jpg
```

Which resolves to the correct image.

Something is clearly wrong with the filenames and it seems to me like it is an encoding issue. I tried to solve this with `convmv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 *` but it says all files are already UTF-8 encoded and won't update anything.

**How can i fix filenames with åäö characters after transferring them from another web host?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`convmv` is right: the filenames are already UTF-8 encoded.  I think it's still the right tool to use though.

There is more than one way in Unicode to get the `å` glyph.  The first way is that `å` (U+00E5) exists as a character on its own, which is how it's encoded in your link.

But you can also take a normal `a` (U+0061), and add the circle `̊` (U+030A) as a combining character, to get `å`.  And something during the migration must have re-encoded your filename from the first representation to the second.

The [man page of `convmv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/convmv) makes reference to "normalization form C" (used on Linux) and "normalization form D" (used on OS X).  From experimentation, it looks like form C represents `å` as its own character, and form D represents `å` using the combining circle.

Back up your files so you have a known checkpoint if something goes awry, then try the following:

```
convmv --nfc -f utf8 -t utf8 *
```

---

Alternately, you could try the migration again and dodge the re-encoding issue completely.

If you have shell access on the old host, you could create a `tar` archive of the site (`tar czf my_site.tar.gz my_site_directory`), then copy the archive to the new host and extract it there (`tar xzf my_site.tar.gz`).  This will shield the filenames from changes as they're now data inside another file.

Comment: About the different normalization forms: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: Amazing, it worked like a charm :)